# Static result in a recursive Haskell function?

Tags: string, haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell programming and have gotten an assignment to create a function that checks if a given string is the substring of another string and if it is it returns the position of the substring in the main string. This is what I have so far:

```
findString :: String -> String -> Integer
findString mainstring substring 
   | length substring > length mainstring = (-1)
   | take (length substring) mainstring == substring  = 0
   | otherwise = 1 + findString (drop 1 mainstring) substring
```

The instructions for this assignment explicitly state that I have to use `findString :: String -> String -> Integer` and that if the substring is not a substring of the mainstring it should return `(-1)`. Right now the recursive part of the function interferes with the result of`| length substring > length mainstring = (-1)` by adding `+1` to it for each recursion but I just want a static `(-1)`. I feel like I'm very close here but I've been stuck on this one for quite some time now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fix your thoughts on the type signatures, you can have define functions inside a function as well

```
findString :: String -> String -> Integer
findString mainstring substring = helper mainstring substring 0
  where 
    helper mainstring substring len
      | length substring > length mainstring = (-1)
      | take (length substring) mainstring == substring = len
      | otherwise = helper (drop 1 mainstring) substring (len + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was thinking something like this, a separate variable for counting) just did'nt know what that woud look like in haskell. I didn't really know the syntax for `where` so I will have to look into that properly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just doing `otherwise = 1 + findString (drop 1 mainstring) substring`, compare the value with `-1` first. Look up `let` and `where` in your study materials, they will help. I think that's enough given it's an assignment.